# Override default date rage for DayGridMonth view

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have been looking high and low and so far have seen no options via the code or anything else that seems to even come close to what i am asking.  My request is simple enough.   Typically when we want to display in a month grid view the month of September 2019 we expect the start of this month to be 9/1/2019 and the end to be 9/30/2019 with anything before or after to be considered other month.

However, I need for my calendar to have a different date range for the month of September 2019.   This is so that it aligns with how we manage months.   With the exception of the month of October all other months of the year are modified for different date range.

```
January = 01/01 to 01/30
February = 01/31 to 03/01
March = 03/02 to 03/31
April = 04/01 to 05/01
May = 05/02 to 06/01
June = 06/02 to 07/01
July = 07/02 to 07/31
August = 08/01 to 08/30
September = 08/31 to 09/30
October = 10/01 to 10/31
November = 11/01 to 12/01
December = 12/02 to 12/31
```

In many cases I do not need to make many adjustments (just some add/remove "fc-other-month" class,  as the previous months ending dates are also visible (if using the 6 week enabled flag, which is also set by default), however, in September 2019, 09/01 is on a Sunday of the first week meaning that the previous week that would include 8/31 is not rendered.

I can explore a "brute force" type method of checking for this condition and then prepending another row on top of week 1 with the additional dates needed but I have to believe that there is a simple method where i can simply state the  months start and end date range.

Comment: No, the month grid view is pretty fixed in its layout, unfortunately. There's no option in the API to enable what you're talking about. The other view types are more flexible and can be manipulated using the various duration, visibleRange, dayCount options - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-views. But of course they may not provide the visual layout you're aiming for. Or you have the nuclear option of forking the dayGrid plugin (or starting from scratch, if you really want some pain!) and creating a totally "custom view" aligned to your precise requirements.

Comment: ADyson, yes, that was what i was running into.....list and other views were more flexible which is great but i needed the main calendar to be that way also....I will continue down the path of creating a fullcalendar plugin / addon that can hopefully address the needs.  Myself personally, I am good with a traditional calendar view but i know my target user base and most of them will petition to have it match their contract language for calendar days.

Comment: I suppose a third option is to submit a feature request to allow the month grid to be more flexible, but (not being involved in the project) I've no idea if it would be accepted or how long you'd have to wait. You could try adding the functionality to the existing daygrid plugin yourself and submitting a patch (which would almost certainly speed up the release process if it's accepted, since no-one else has to code it). Maybe have a chat with the maintainers via GitHub about how keen they'd be on that before you decide whether to do that or to make your own plugin.

Comment: P.S. Just a small linguistic/technical point - the "month" view isn't the "main calendar", it's just one view type. It's generally selected by default if you include the dayGrid plugin in the calendar and don't specify any other view as default, but it's certainly not an integral or essential component of fullCalendar - it will [run quite happily without it](https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRKZJZo).

Comment: OK, good news.    I was able to get this finally listed as a bug.  Seems that the dayGrid has a feature to do what i am after but it is currently broken as it only works in a full year mode (01JAN to 31DEC),  They now have it on the break/fix list.

Comment: @BobTate any links to the feature please or discussion on it by the team